# Answer the unanswered!

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

We have been making great progress with our site, with some wonderful stats.

However, there are about [460 unanswered questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/unanswered) in the site. Some are very old and some are ignored at the time when there was very less traffic here.

So, let's  try to  dig into them and try to give the best answers, and try to improve on the `% answered` stat. (We're at 76%)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also help by flagging questions that are not answered because they're off-topic, unclear, etc. I can take a look and close them if so. That's the right thing to do, and happens to also be reflected in the % answered statistic.

Also @Dawny33 maybe we should make you a moderator.

Comment: Yeah, sanitizing the unanswered queue also needs to be done, along with a lot of [off-topic old questions](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/334/what-do-you-think-of-data-science-certifications)  And as someone who have [seen the site grow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266067/302377) from nothing to what it is now,  I would be very happy to step up as a mod, if given a chance :)

Comment: That was a pretty easy event to forecast, wasn't it?